# Editar arquivo Xml C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com uma pequena dificuldade em editar um xml.

Recebo a seguinte xml:

```xml
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.00"> 
    <CTe CTemlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte">
        <infCte versao="3.00" Id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <compl>Preciso inserir uma estrutura aqui!</compl>
        </infCte>
    </CTe>
</cteProc>
```

Entre as tags `<compl> </compl>` preciso inserir a seguinte estrutura.

```
<ObsCont xCampo="vContainer"><xTexto>valor</xTexto></ObsCont>
```

Tentei editar com o seguinte código.

```cs
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\ArquivosXML\" + integracao.NOME + ".xml");
       xdoc.Root.Add(xdoc.Element("Cte"), xdoc.Element("compl"),
           new XElement("ObsCont",
               new XAttribute("xCampo", "vContainer"),
               new XElement("xTexto", "valor")
               )
       );
       xdoc.Save(@"C:\ArquivosXML\" + integracao.NOME + ".xml");
```

Com o código acima estou consigo inserir mais entre as tags `<cteProc> </cteProc>`

E quando insiro a elemento `ObsCont` está salvando `<ObsCont xmlns= "" xCampo="vContainer">` o correto é `<ObsCont xCampo="vContainer">` sem o xmlns= "".

Comment: Recomendo que você veja sobre serealização de xml em c#. Eu trabalho com xmls como esse do CTE que você precisa e, para facilitar (e muito) minha vida, eu modelo o xml em classes onde eu serealizo e deserealizo do xml para objeto e vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode colocar um .Replace("xmlns=\"","");

Eu já trabalhei com nota fiscal eletrônica e usava bastante replace em algumas situações específicas.

Comment: O .Replace só iria resolver uma parte do meu problema, gostaria de manipular o xml corretamente. Estou utilizando o .Replace para resolver temporariamente o meu problema desta forma : string xml = integracao.xml;
            string xmlEditado = xml.Replace("</compl>", "<ObsCont xCampo=\"vContainer\"><xTexto>"+integracao.vl_Container+"</xTexto></ObsCont></compl>");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlEditado);
            xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\XML\" + integracao.NOME + ".xml");
            integracao.Path = @"C:\XML\"+integracao.NOME+".xml";